# MIPS Beq Add/Subtract Switch

Tags: mips

I am new to MIPS trying to figure out Branches and Switches. All I want to do is set switch 0 to add and switch 1 to subtract. Can someone help and explain what I am doing wrong because every video I watch does not help. Every time I run the program I previously had, all it did was run the add: switch over and over again.

```
li $a0, 2
li $a1, 1

main:
li $s0, 0xf0100000
li $s1, 0b00000001
li $s2, 0b00000010

start:
lw $t0, 0($s0)
beq                <------ This is what I don't understand
nop

add:
addu $v0, $a0, $a1
j start
nop

subtract:
subu $v0, $a0, $a1
j start
nop
```

Comment: That code wouldn't assemble, because `beq` requires 3 operands and you've provided none.

Comment: I understand that. The code that I have done only runs the add switch and does not include the subtraction at all, therefore I did not write that out. What would you use to include both?

Comment: Just do a conditional jump based on some value that you want to compare. As for why the code at `add` runs over and over; that's simply because there's nothing that stops it from doing so. You're never terminating your program.