# MIPS SIMPLE BEQ ADDITION OR SUBTRACTION

Tags: branch, mips

What I am trying to do is use switch values of 1 jump to the addition and 2 to jump to the subtraction. I do not understand why or how to set up the beq correctly. Can someone explain how to do this correctly and where I am going wrong?

```
li $a0, 2
li $a1, 1

main:
li $s0, 0xf0100000
li $s1, 0b00000001
li $s2, 0b00000010

start:
lw $t0, 0($s0)
beq $s1, $t0 add
beq $s2, $t0 subtract
nop

add:
addu $v0, $a0, $a1
j start
nop

subtract:
subu $v0, $a0, $a1
j start
nop
```

Comment: You need to provide a better explanation of what the problem is. One obvious thing is that you've got an inifinte loop, since you're jumping back to `start`, and `$s0` never changes, so you'll be executing the same set of instructions over and over.

Comment: And in what way is this different from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32418253/mips-beq-add-subtract-switch ?  To me this just looks like a re-post of the same question with slightly changed wording.